# How can I automatically syntax check a powershell script file?

Tags: validation, powershell

I want to write a unit-test for some code which generates a powershell script and then check that the script has valid syntax.

What's a good way to do this without actually executing the script?

A .NET code solution is ideal, but a command line solution that I could use by launching an external process would be good enough.

Comment: Related post - [How to do full syntax check of PowerShell script file using the PowerShell cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68397836/465053)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could run your code through the [`Parser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.language.parser(v=vs.85).aspx) and observe if it raises any errors:

```
# Empty collection for errors
$Errors = @()

# Define input script
$inputScript = 'Do-Something -Param 1,2,3,'

[void][System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($inputScript,[ref]$null,[ref]$Errors)

if($Errors.Count -gt 0){
    Write-Warning 'Errors found'
}
```

This could easily be turned into a simple function:

```
function Test-Syntax
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='File')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='File', Position = 0)]
        [string]$Path, 

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='String', Position = 0)]
        [string]$Code
    )

    $Errors = @()
    if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'String'){
        [void][System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($Code,[ref]$null,[ref]$Errors)
    } else {
        [void][System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseFile($Path,[ref]$null,[ref]$Errors)
    }

    return [bool]($Errors.Count -lt 1)
}
```

Then use like:

```
if(Test-Syntax C:\path\to\script.ps1){
    Write-Host 'Script looks good!'
}
```

Comment: This is likely the most direct on-point answer to the question.  Mine is more general unit testing.

Comment: If someone could make this answer a bit more dummy proof, I'd appreciate it. Do I understand correctly that the first and the second code are redundant? Or rather: it's the second one I'm supposed to use?

Comment: Could it be that to use the function, you need the `-path` option? For me only `Test-Syntax -path C:\path\to\script.ps1` seems to work, not `Test-Syntax C:\path\to\script.ps1`

Answer (score 28):

I stumbled onto `Get-Command -syntax 'script.ps1'` and found it concise and useful.

**ETA** from the comment below: This gives a detailed syntax error report, if any; otherwise it shows the calling syntax (parameter list) of the script.

Comment: For me, this just produces the name of the scriupt file.

Comment: Indeed it does.  Now try it on a script that has syntax errors.

Comment: This gives a detailed syntax error report, if any; otherwise it shows the calling syntax (parameter list) of the script. This is much easier to use for a quick error check than the accepted answer.

Comment: @royappa: This answer is only useful because of your comment, which has 10 times more information than the answer. +1 for both.

Comment: This is just entirely awesome.

Answer (score 5):

[PS Script Analyzer](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSScriptAnalyzer/1.11.0) is a good place to start at static analysis of your code.

> PSScriptAnalyzer provides script analysis and checks for potential
>   code defects in the scripts by applying a group of built-in or
>   customized rules on the scripts being analyzed.

It also integrates with [Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

There are a number of strategies for mocking PowerShell as part of unit tests, and also have a look at Pester.

The Scripting Guy's [Unit Testing PowerShell Code With Pester](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/12/16/unit-testing-powershell-code-with-pester/)
PowerShellMagazine's [Get Started With Pester (PowerShell unit testing framework)](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/03/12/get-started-with-pester-powershell-unit-testing-framework/)